# How to use multiple classes in Android

Tags: java, android, function, methods, extends

Hi How do I use multiple classes in android? i.e. I have a button in my mainActivity Class.I want to call a method of a different class when I press the button like display a Toast message.
Thanks in advance :)

When I run This code my app crashes.
Here is what I have tried.

```
package myplayground.dreamingreality.com.myplayground;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Ruben on 16/08/10.
 */
public class OtherClass extends Activity{

    // Here is my other class

    public Toast mess()
    {

        Toast t =  null;
        t.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Here is my Main Class

```
package myplayground.dreamingreality.com.myplayground;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                OtherClass oC = new OtherClass();
                oC.mess().show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem, what did you try ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question. May I suggest reading the [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) and [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) and learning basic Java online

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `OnClickListener` for your button. It looks like this:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myANotherClass.showToast("test text");
    }
});
```

There are the basics: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: Why your other class extends Activity? if you need to start an activity - you shold do it by intent. If you need just create POJO object - don't extend from Activity :)

Comment: And if you want to receive helpful answers here, at StackOverFlow - i recomend you to post exception stacktrace. Cuz "my app crashed" can have a million reasons :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't allow **Multiple Class Inheritance**. If that's what you were trying to do. 
Showing a simple `Toast` doesn't require you to `extend` multiple classes.

If you were going to run a method in another `Activity` or a class, you can make that method `static`, and  then simply call:

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    YourClass.yourMethod();
    }
});
```

**Good Luck!**

Comment: Thanks for the help :)